# Is "I guess that therapist I found for you, she really helped." an ellipsis of a that-clause?

Tags: sentence-structure

> ‘I guess that therapist I found for you, she really helped.’ *good 4 u - Olivia Rodrigo*

Could you teach me what it means? It’s an ellipsis of a *that*-clause?

Comment: "ellipsis" means the *removal* of some text element. What you have here is ***repetition*** of the subject. It's completely unnecessary / stylistically optional to include a second reference to the subject using pronoun ***she*** here. The "standard" version of the utterance would just be *I guess that therapist I found for you really helped* - stripped of other unnecessary elements, ***That therapist really helped [you]***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If so, does it need a comma after ‘she’?

Comment: Note that the single instance of ***that*** in your example is a (syntactically *necessary*; either ***that, this,*** or another determiner such as the definite article ***the***) "relativiser" within the "that- clause". The ***optional*** word "that" for the that-clause could also be included: *I guess **that that** therapist I found for you, she really helped* is perfectly okay (note that the first "that" would only carry very light stress).

Comment: ***If and only if*** the word "she" is included, it *must* have a comma ***before*** it (reflecting a detectable pause in speech). No other commas should be used.

Comment: Is that what you meant by "an ellipsis of a *that*-clause"? The missing optional *second* instance of the word "that"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, I think ‘she really helped’ is a separate clause, and the verb of ‘therapist’ is omitted.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. As I pointed out, the basic underlying assertion here is ***The therapist helped** [you].* Extended by the speaker explicitly identifying ***that*** therapist as the one that he found for the addressee, and with the assertion "tempered / hedged" by ***I guess*** (as in ***I think** the therapist helped you, but I don't **know** that for sure*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that 'you' in that song introduced the therapist for 'me', and she (the therapist) really helped me. In terms of structure, I guess that / the therapist (I found for you), she really helped.  So the therapist=she. 'I found for you' modifies 'the therapist' as an adjective phrase.

Comment: to you, dear, to you.